# mariaDB JSON_SET command

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have been working with the JSON **COLUMN_CREATE** and **COLUMN_JSON** options in mariaDB.  how do i update just one JSON column without having to extract the entire JSON column?

i see that mysql now has a **JSON_SET** option.   is this something that mariaDB will add?
when i first switched over from mysql to mariaDB the documentation seemed to elude to mariaDB being a "drop-in" replacement for mysql.

also, i thought i read initially that if mysql comes out with a new feature, mariaDB will match the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"drop-in replacement" = "marketing".  However, it is *mostly* true.

You have ventured into a very new feature (JSON) of Oracle MySQL, for which MariaDB has not (yet) caught up.  I cannot say when (or even 'if') it will catch up in this.

Meanwhile, MariaDB has added a number of features that have not (yet) been adopted by Oracle.

Comment: i heard back from the mariaDB people - JSON_XXX in 10.2 alpha testing now.

Comment: Give it a try and let us know if they implementations are the same.  :)

Comment: Actually it looks like COLUMN_ADD might do just what i am trying to accomplish, for now anyways.   However, i think the true "drop-in replacement" might be to use CockroachDB instead.   That being said, I sure enjoyed your "marketing" comment.